# Visualização de conteúdo no Delphi Seattle

Tags: delphi, mobile, embarcadero

Estou tentando resolver um detalhe de um projeto mobile que tenho, o qual é desenvolvido em Delphi Seattle. 
**Gostaria de saber se existe a possibilidade de alterar dinamicamente (por componente nativo, de terceiros estes pagos ou free) a visualização de uma lista de conteúdos**.

Hoje listo meus dados em um `listview` com multi detalhes, bem similar ao exemplo que vem com o próprio Delphi.
Gostaria que o usuário pudesse escolher entre lista de itens ou miniaturas, parecido com a visualização do conteúdo do Google Drive.

Comment: Já pensou em colocar uma opção no app pra mudar isso e apenas trocar a `ListView.PublishedAppearance.ItemAppearance`?

Comment: Olá, infelizmente não me ajuda. Já havia repassado essas propriedades. O que preciso é de algo que mostre em forma de lista os dados do meu BD e quando eu quiser essa lista se transforme em miniatura. uma do lado da outra. Nas opções desta propriedade existe a miniatura mas elas continua em forma de lista. preciso de algo que mostra lado a lado os itens. algo como https://projects.invisionapp.com/share/KEBTJ4N5D#/screens/234957475